# Include ability to search users by created date

Tags: feature-request, search, moderator-tools, users, time

We have the ability to search for users by a variety of methods in the moderator tools. However, when searching it will return all matching data when we might need to be more selective in our search, including users created in the past month, etc.

Can additional search options be added, including a date parameter?